# Preventing Outlook calendar from adding @mentioned users as invitees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

In the Microsoft Outlook thick client for Mac allows you to mention users when drafting a calendar invitation by using the format `@username`.

I want to use this functionality to accurately mention somebody's name, and ensure that I'm not misspelling their name. Outlook additionally automatically adds mentioned users to the attendees list of the meeting.

This additional behavior is not desired, as I do not want to invite these individuals to the meeting. I simply wish to uniquely and correctly identify them in the text in the meeting body. Automatically adding them to the meeting has the negative effect of sending an invitation to somebody for a meeting that they do not need to attend, which must then be declined or rescinded by the sender, creating annoying and slightly embarrassing spam.

Is there a way to configure Outlook so that it will not add mentioned users to the attendees list? Or at least to prompt before it adds the users?

Answer (score 0):

I use and have used Outlook calendaring for a very long time. On meetings where a person invites several and I respond, there are no attendees shown in the meeting appointment. When a person schedules a meeting, they would normally do it from Contacts which gets the correct name.

Otherwise to your specific question, there is no native ability in Outlook Calendaring to fill your need.

For advising people, I just use Notes in the Appointment notes area. Notes can also be used for Zoom information and even documents.

So Outlook Notes is the way to handle your situation. You must enter the names as you wish, as it is not in any way automatic.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John. The mentioned user receives an invitation to the meeting. It's by design. There is currently no option to block it.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.